# Compiling on the desktop!! no?

Tags: files, compiling, directory

so I have compile my first program today, with the help of the "askubuntu's members"..... thanks so much!!! ;)

this is what I have compiled : https://github.com/treeder/logitech_unifier

But now, I have some question:

1- I have compiled my file on the desktop I have though it was easier first, but I never though it would create a file on my desktop...... so what do you guys do with the file created by the compilation?

I don't think I need it anymore.... so do I delete it? or  do I keep it?
Is there a folder I should specificaly use for compiling?

thanks for answering those newbies question.

Answer (score 1):

The whole compiling process is very simple.

1)Install the Gcc compiler by typing `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

2)Change your directory to Desktop `cd /home/your_user_name/Desktop`

3)Compile by typing `gcc file_name.c`

4)Then run the created .out program by typing `./a.out`